# I am trying to read specific number of files from a collection of files according to month and year

Tags: python

```
def monthly_report(year,month):
    pre_script="Murree_weather"
    format='.txt'
    file_name=pre_script + year + month+format
    file = open(file_name,"r")
    print(file.readline())
    return
monthly_report("_2004","_Dec")
```

Above is my code but i am getting errors:

> File "C:/Users/MY PC/PycharmProjects/lab 3/lab3.py", line 12, in 
>       monthly_report("_2004","_Dec")
>     File "C:/Users/MY PC/PycharmProjects/lab 3/lab3.py", line 8, in monthly_report
>       file = open(file_name,"r")
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Murree_weather_2004_Dec.txt'

Comment: The file you're trying to open does not exist. Are you sure the name is correct?

Comment: i have a collection of files in a folder which is in that directory

Comment: Are you running the script inside a folder containing 'Murree_weather' files?

Comment: You'll probably need to specify the full path to your file then.

Answer (score 0):

With no modifications your code ran and worked for me, very easily you could be overlooking that you are not in the same directory as the file.

```
def monthly_report(year, month):
    pre_script = "Murree_weather"
    format = ".txt"
    file_name = pre_script + year + month + format
    file = open(file_name, "r")
    print(file.readline())
    return

monthly_report("_2004", "_Dec")
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 monthly_report.py 
> This is Murree
> ```